# What is the syntax to pass an array of Sprites into the Tweener Class in Actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays, syntax

This works:

```
Tweener.addTween( [ _fee, _fye, _fum ] , { alpna:1, time:10 });
```

But this does not:

```
var _myArray:Array = new Array( [ _fee, _fye, _fum ] );
Tweener.addTween( _myArray , { alpna:1, time:10 });
```

How can I pass the an array straight into the tweener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should call the constructor like this:

```
var _myArray:Array = new Array(_fee, _fye, _fum);
```

what you did, is construct an `Array`, that contains an `Array` of `MovieClip`s ...
just as a side note: personally, i see no advantage of not using the literal, as in the first case ... sometimes it is even better, because it is less ambigous ... for example `new Array(5)` will construct an `Array` of length 5, whereas `new Array(myObject)` will construct an `Array` containing `myObject` ...